# Getting current path on server wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Today I am adding a custom code to wordpress page.php to manage form data including file upload. I just want to check the real page so I can give the path to upload the file in code.

I have this code to upload the file:

```
$target = "uploads/"; 
$target = $target . basename($_FILES['pass_doc']['name']); 
//Here we check that $ok was not set to 0 by an error 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pass_doc']['tmp_name'], $target);
$pass_doc = $_FILES['pass_doc']['name'];
```

But I don't know target path should I give I tried:

```
$target = "example.org/uploads/";
```

But its also not working for me. Please give any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, when you says `uploads/`, that will be always a relative path to your current directory. Use the wordpress `wp_upload_dir()` function. Check the documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir)

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$target = $upload_dir['baseurl'] . "/" . basename($_FILES['pass_doc']['name']);
```